# What happened to VaadinWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter in Vaadin 19?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-spring-boot, hilla, vaadin-fusion

We are building a web app with Vaadin 19 Fusion, and I'm following this tutorial:
https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/fusion/security/spring-login
(I have selected the V19+ Docs and then Fusion)

In the tutorial there is a reference to `VaadinWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` which is used for setting up the security with Spring, but this class is not available on the classpath. I have tried downloading a plain starter project (v19) from start.vaadin.com, and here I am also not able to use `VaadinWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`.

Is there an alternative in v19 or am I missing a dependency? I have the same dependency tree as the starter project, so I was assuming the pom is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the `VaadinWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` will end up in V20, which is scheduled for release in June.

The documentation page you linked has a tag `V20 pre-release` at the top. This could certainly be made more visible.